# How to use regex for a single character in a String?

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I have the following String :

```
LoopStep(i,0,m-1,1)
```

and I want to use regex so that I will find just the first "(" ,for example my regex code is : `\\([^)]*\\)`. I want to check for the 1st open parenthesis only so I don't have a problem with this code:

```
LoopStep ((i,0,m-1,1)).
```

Comment: If you just want to find the position of the first `(` then use the `indexOf` method of class `String`, you don't need a regular expression for somehing this simple: `int index = input.indexOf('(');`

Comment: why do you need regex ? [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

Comment: you don't use quotes?

Comment: Well i have to check if after the LoopStep there will be an opened paranthesis and if the String ends with a closed paranthesis

Comment: Just wondering - if he really wants to allow any "good" combination, like ( ), (( )), ((( ))) and so on; can this kind of "counting" be done with regular expressions; or do you actually need a compiler for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *only* want to check on whether your `String` doesn't contain two consecutive parenthesis, you can use `indexOf` or `contains` instead of regular expressions:

```
// will return true only if the String doesn't contain ((
// you can also use to infer actual index
test.indexOf("((") == -1
// same and better but you can't use the index
!test.contains("((")
```

Note that here, `test` is your desired `String` variable, e.g. with value `"LoopStep(i,0,m-1,1)"`.

If you're actually parsing a syntax, which appears to be the case, do not use regular expressions.

You will likely have to build your own parser in order to verify and parse the syntax of your meta-language.

**Note**

Just to give you a glimpse of what mess you might be getting into if you use regular expressions to validate the syntax in this case, here's a regex example matching your whole `String` to check against consecutive parenthesis (`"(("`):

```
//           | non-parenthesis
//           |    | or
//           |    | | not preceded by parenthesis
//           |    | |      | actual parenthesis
//           |    | |      |  | not followed by parenthesis
//           |    | |      |  |       | 1+ length(adjust with desired quantifier)
test.matches("([^(]|(?<!\\()\\((?!=\\())+")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the question mark. If you add it to a regular expression, it becomes non-greedy. For instance, the pattern "(" will match all your open brackets, meanwhile "(?" will only match the first occurrence.

Comment: and for the last one? i have tried with \Z but for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: Do you want to match the first of the closed brackets or the last one?

Comment: I need to check both of them,if the LoopStep is followed by "(" and it ends with ")"

Comment: then add this condition to your question

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. Can't you just use \(.*\) as a pattern? This will match this (i,0,m-1,1) and this ((i,0,m-1,1)) in the OP. Then, if it matches, you will know for sure that the brackets are there. Try it here: https://regex101.com/